# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT * FROM

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using Sql Server 2008, developed a view "vw_MasterView" I get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT * FROM VW_MASTERVIEW v WHERE 1=1  AND v.ClinicId = '' to data type int.
```

when I run the following stored procedure:

```
USE [xxxxxxx]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClientSummary1]
    @LocationId int,
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime,
    @userName nvarchar(50)
AS
    declare @sql nvarchar(2000);
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM VW_MASTERVIEW v WHERE 1=1 ';
    IF @LocationId is not null
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND v.LocationId = ''' + @LocationId + '''';
    end
    if @userName is not null
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND (v.FirstUser = '' OR v.SecondUser = '')' + @userName + '''';
    end
    if @startDate is not null 
    begin
       set @sql = @sql + ' AND v.FirstVisitDate = ''' + @startDate + ''''; 
    end
    if @endDate is not null 
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND v.LastVisitDate = ''' + @endDate + ''''; 
    end

    EXEC(@sql)
```

I get both the LocationId and userName from a VS2010 application.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` and parameterised queries. Your concatenation of `@userName` is a SQL Injection risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When appending strings together in SQL Server, you have to cast non-textual types (such as `int`) to a textual type (such as `varchar`):

```
set @sql = @sql + ' AND v.LocationId = ''' +
    cast(@LocationId as varchar(10)) + '''';
--  ^^^^ have to cast           ^^ make sure size is big enough
```

Note that dynamic SQL should not be necessary in the first place.  You can just run the query directly with the parameters (I implemented the null checks with the extra `or` conditions):

```
SELECT * FROM VW_MASTERVIEW v
 WHERE (v.LocationId = @LocationId    OR @LocationId is null)
   AND (v.FirstUser = @userName OR v.Seconduser = @userName OR @userName is null)
   AND (v.FirstVisitDate = @startDate OR @startDate is null)
   AND (v.LastVisitDate = @endDate    OR @endDate is null)
```

I may not have the logic right for `FirstUser` and `SecondUser` - I took an educated guess from your incomplete code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great except I am get now an error Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. for this line ' AND (v.FirstUser = '' OR v.SecondUser = '')'